# How to merge bins in R

Tags: r

So, I am trying to merge bins of a histogram whenever the number of observations in a bin is less than 6.

```
library(fitdistrplus)
mydata <-read.csv("Book2.csv",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
QF3<-as.numeric(mydata[,1])
histrv<-hist(QF3,breaks="FD")
binvec<-data.frame(diff(histrv$breaks))
binbreak=histrv$breaks
freq<-histrv$count
datmean=as.numeric(mean(QF3))
datsigma=as.numeric(sd(QF3))
templist<-as.numeric()#empty list
for (i in 1:nrow(binvec)){
  templist[i]=pnorm(binbreak[i+1],datmean,datsigma)-pnorm(binbreak[i],datmean,datsigma)
}
pi<-data.frame(templist)
chisqvec<-(freq-length(QF3)*pi)^2/(length(QF3)*pi)
xstat=sum(chisqvec)
```

The above code will provide a histogram with five bins that contain less than 6 observations, which are the bins 6000-7000, 7000-8000, 8000-9000, 9000-10000, and 10000-11000. Each of these 5 bins contain 2, 5, 2, 2, and 1 observations respectively. I would like to merge the bins that they can have more than 5 observations.

In other words, I would like to have the two bins 6000-8000 and 8000-11000 so that they can contain 7 observations and 5 observations.

Does anyone have any clue on how to approach this problem?

QF3 looks like the following:

```
> QF3
 [1]  2016  1425  2000   785   823  2484  1870   770  1220  3454  1056  2745  2830
[14]   950   601  1245  2663  1500  1717  1070  1704  2517  1090  3310  3389  2200
[27]   882  2113   600  1900  4417   745   530  1630  1600  4530   948  2764  2202
[40]  1052  2685  1120  1275  2300  1590  1935  3957  4283  3215  5684  4092  7548
[53]  4547  3510  3063  5549  6460  5204  4626  4965  5023  8111  5525  4804  5994
[66]  8471  4767  7142  3420  4061  5102  9135  3861  5372  7274  5054  7318  3791
[79]  4901  3549  4758  4859 10190  5609  7624  5841  4908  4974  6691  5713  3235
[92]  4464  2656  4399  9581  3993  4061
```