# Pandas Merge Bins

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe, histogram

I have created a distribution using numpy histogram and digitize functions.

```
_, bins = np.histogram(x, bins=bins)
arr = np.digitize(x, bins) - 1
x = bins[arr[:]]
```

Or possibly:

```
x = pandas.cut(x, bins=bins)
```

However as the distribution is very skewed, even after removing outliers, there are many bins with very little observations. I want to merge bins, somewhat similar to:

[How to merge bins in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22290018/how-to-merge-bins-in-r)

The procedure would possibly involve pandas groupby and then merging the group sizes less than `n` to their neighbouring values. Is there a way to achieve this in pandas/numpy?

Comment: Can you get away with using `pd.cut`?

Comment: @JonClements I dont seem to get how that can help in this case

Comment: Yeah wasn't sure if you could just use `cut` and provide it the number of bins so you get an automatic distribution... but that won't work if you *have* to have defined bins...

Comment: Interesting question. I will think about including such feature in my histogramming library `physt` - https://github.com/janpipek/physt (but probably not sooner than when you find your answer ;-))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As promised, I implemented something in physt, version 0.3.5. You're welcome to use it.

See http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/janpipek/physt/blob/master/doc/Binning2.ipynb#Merging-bins and particularly http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/janpipek/physt/blob/master/doc/Binning2.ipynb#By-min-frequency

In your case, the workflow would be something like this:

```
import physt
histogram = physt.h1(x, bins=bins)
histogram.merge_bins(min_frequency=n)
bins = histogram.numpy_bins
```

Note that the code is in alpha stage and not each bin contains more than the required minimum (in order to preserve tall narrow bins). The best algorithm is still being looked for.

Comment: Will check it out!